# Select only a specific keys within a nested MapType col using pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Given a dataframe with nested MapType object and hashed out top level key, how do I filter out subkeys within the nested map?

Below is an example with sample input and expected output. Here I would like to filterout nested maps with `fname` & `lname` as keys.

INPUT :-

```
{
  'h#9l00' : {
     'fname': 'fname1',
     'lname': 'lname1',
     'salary': 100,
     'city': 'xyz'
  },
  'o*5ftr': {
     'fname': 'fname2',
     'lname': 'lname2',
     'city': 'xyz'
  }
}
```

OUTPUT :-

```
{
  'h#9l00' : {
     'salary': 100,
     'city': 'xyz'
  },
  'o*5ftr': {
     'city': 'xyz'
  }
}
```

Is there a way to write a pyspark UDF to do solve this usecase if I know the list of keys I want to remove or keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df.show()

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                                                                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{o*5ftr -> {fname -> fname2, lname -> lname2, city -> xyz}, h#9l00 -> {fname -> fname1, lname -> lname1, salary -> 100, city -> xyz}}|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Code

There's no need to use UDF which are inherently slow. Here we can use builtin higher order functions to achieve the result. Apply a value transformation function to each key, value pair in the outer map, then apply a map filter on the inner map to remove the predefined `keys`

```
keys = ['fname', 'lname']
func = F.transform_values('col', lambda _, x: F.map_filter(x, lambda k, _: ~k.isin(keys)))
result = df.withColumn('col', func)
```

#### Result

```
result.show()

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|{o*5ftr -> {city -> xyz}, h#9l00 -> {salary -> 100, city -> xyz}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you. This is super helpful. 

Any chance you know how to do this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76149347/convert-string-values-in-nested-maptype-object-to-arraymaptype