# Convert string values in nested MapType object to array<MapType>

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying work with a nested MapType object and clean out some unnecessary keys. This nested object has some optional keys which need to be casted appropriately and parse through the keys to filter them. Below is an example input and output I would like to achieve.

In the below input I think there are steps I would to do :-

1. Convert the `reports` key (if present) into Array
2. Remove `name` key from each Map within above array.

Column Schema :-

```
 |-- col_name: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

INPUT :-

```
{
  'h#9l00' : {
     'reports': '[{"name":"abc1", "id": "emp1"}, {"name":"abc2", "id": "emp2"}]',
     'salary': 100,
     'city': 'xyz'
  },
  'o*5ftr': {
     'city': 'pqr',
     'salary': 1000
  }
}
```

OUTPUT :-

```
{
  'h#9l00' : {
     'reports': '[{"id": "emp1"}, {"id": "emp2"}]',
     'salary': 100,
     'city': 'xyz'
  },
  'o*5ftr': {
     'city': 'pqr',
     'salary': 1000
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to go about achieving this?

Comment: Can you put the result of .printSchema command of the input dataframe in description ?

Comment: Added column schema